# Data returning not populating ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a ListView with data but for some reason this data is not playing well with my ListView. The data is being retrieved from my server and outputting an error in MainClass with the JSONException. Error is "String can not be converted to JSONArray". Any ideas?

AdapterTeam Class:

```
public class AdapterTeam extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataTeam> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataTeam current;
//int currentPos=0;

// create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
public AdapterTeam(Context context, List<DataTeam> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int  viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_team, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataTeam current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.textteamName.setText(current.teamName);
    myHolder.textSport.setText("Sport: " + current.sport);
    myHolder.textGender.setText("Gender: " + current.gender);
    myHolder.textAge.setText("Age " + current.age );



 }

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView textteamName;
    TextView textSport;
    TextView textAge;
    TextView textGender;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textteamName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textteamName);
        textSport = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSport);
        textGender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textGender);
        textAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAge);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Click event for all items
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

}
```

MainClass: (Adapter)

```
           List<DataTeam> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(joinTeam.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataTeam teamData = new DataTeam();
                    teamData.teamName = json_data.getString("team_name");
                    teamData.sport = json_data.getString("sport");
                    teamData.gender = json_data.getString("gender");
                    teamData.age = json_data.getString("age");
                    data.add(teamData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mTeam = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterTeam(joinTeam.this, data);
                mTeam.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mTeam.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(joinTeam.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                Toast.makeText(joinTeam.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(joinTeam.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: If you see the toast with the json, it means that you catched a `JSONException`. in the exception you should be able to read more details.

Comment: @GVillani82 - You are right - the Toast is happening inside the JSONException. The error is String cannot be converted to JsonArray - so I'd guess how its being returned is the issue..

Comment: Are you sure the root object of your result is an array?  I've seen this when the root JSON object is actually a singular object holding an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after update the adapter list data.